# Electron + Webpack module federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-module-federation

I am using module federation for my micro frontend apps. For the web version, everything is ok, but now I need to create an electron app. How can I do one general bundle of all apps with module federation? or do you know another solution for works Electron with micro react apps?

Comment: start with this one https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template